# How to best store a timestamp in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, timestamp, timezone, utc-time

I'm working on a PostgreSQL DB design and I am wondering how best to store timestamps.

#### Assumptions

Users in different timezones will use the database for all CRUD functions.

I have looked at 2 options:

- `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')`
- `bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT`

For **`timestamp`** I would send a string that would represent the exact (UTC) timestamp for the INSERT moment.

For **`bigint`** I would store the exact same thing, but in a number format. (time zone issues are handled before millis is handed over to the server, so always millis in UTC.)

One main advantage with storing a `bigint` could be that it would be easier to store and to retrieve, as passing a correctly formatted timestamp is more complex than a simple number (millis since Unix Epoc).

My question is which one would allow for the most flexible design and what could be the pitfalls of each approach.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why a timestamp is better than a bigint for representing timestamps. I can't think of of a single reason why a bigint would be better than a timestamp.

Comment: The main reason I can think a BigInt can be easier is that it might be a lot easier to retrieve and store. I will update my questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Store timestamps as `timestamp`, or rather **[`timestamptz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)** (`timestamp with time zone`) since you are dealing with *multiple time zones*. That enforces valid data and is typically most efficient. Be sure to understand the data type, there are some misconceptions floating around:

- [Time zone storage in PostgreSQL timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876266/939860)
- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

To address your concern:

> passing a correctly formatted timestamp is more complex than a simple number

You can pass and retrieve a UNIX epoch either way if you prefer:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1437346800)
     , extract(epoch FROM timestamptz '2015-07-20 01:00+02');
```

Related:

- [Truncate timestamp to arbitrary intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731753/939860)
- [Aggregating (x,y) coordinate point clouds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642239/939860)

If you want to store the *current* timestamp with writes to the DB, use a `timestamptz` **column with default value `now()`**. The system time on the DB server is typically much more reliable and consistent than multiple clients handing in their respective notion of what time it is.
For `INSERT` it can be as simple as:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  ... -- other columns
, created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

And just don't write to that column. It's filled in automatically.

Comment: This made things clear. In addition to the fact that timestamps are stored as 8-byte integers, essential the same as storing as bigint, storing and retrieving with the "to_timestamp" functions makes this a much simpler choice. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

You should always store data in its native data type so you can use the built-in functions. The data type of a timestamp is: `timestamp`.

As an aside, a `timestamp` is **not** stored as a string, it's stored as an 8-byte integer, exactly the same as `bigint`: [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say that I would *send a string* for storage, not store a timestamp. Corrected it.