# Is there a CASE LIKE in pl/pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a dynamic after trigger function that does an update based on the `TG_TABLE_NAME`, but it seems that plpgsql's CASE cannot do "LIKE". Is it called differently in plpgsql, or impossible?

If not possible, my second idea would be to do a SUBSTR, or are there better ways?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_sys_table()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    lm BIGINT := (EXTRACT(epoch FROM timezone('UTC', now()))*1000)::bigint;
BEGIN
    CASE TG_TABLE_NAME
        WHEN  LIKE 'candy\_%' THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE sys_table SET last_modified = lm, modified_by = NEW.modified_by WHERE sys_table_name = 'xvw_candy';
        END;
        WHEN  LIKE 'fruit\_%' THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE sys_table SET last_modified = lm, modified_by = NEW.modified_by WHERE sys_table_name = 'xvw_fruit';
        END;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'No match';
    END CASE;
        
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This simply updates a record in a table called `sys_table`, which keeps track of a last-modified date for a group of tables. The group of tables are prefixed with either `candy_` and `fruit_` (yes, I made that up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, you have to put the `TG_TABLE_NAME`not behind the case, you have to put it in front of every `LIKE`

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_sys_table()
> RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
> DECLARE
>     lm BIGINT := (EXTRACT(epoch FROM timezone('UTC', now()))*1000)::bigint;
> BEGIN
>     CASE 
>         WHEN  TG_TABLE_NAME LIKE 'candy\_%' THEN
>         BEGIN
>             UPDATE sys_table SET last_modified = lm, modified_by = NEW.modified_by WHERE sys_table_name = 'xvw_candy';
>         END;
>         WHEN  TG_TABLE_NAME LIKE 'fruit\_%' THEN
>         BEGIN
>             UPDATE sys_table SET last_modified = lm, modified_by = NEW.modified_by WHERE sys_table_name = 'xvw_fruit';
>         END;
>     ELSE
>         RAISE NOTICE 'No match';
>     END CASE;
>         
>     RETURN NEW;
> END;
> $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=022624601ca1294909951e9d9f577ef0)*

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out, you got the `CASE` syntax wrong.

You also don't need [sub-blocks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html), parameters, multiple distinct `UPDATE` statements or even the (broken) PL/pgSQL `CASE` construct. Just an SQL `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_sys_table()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE sys_table
   SET    last_modified = EXTRACT(epoch FROM timezone('UTC', now())) * 1000
        , modified_by   = NEW.modified_by
   WHERE  sys_table_name = CASE WHEN TG_TABLE_NAME LIKE 'candy\_%' THEN 'xvw_candy'
                                WHEN TG_TABLE_NAME LIKE 'fruit\_%' THEN 'xvw_fruit'
                           END;
                           
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'No match';
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

Subtle difference: this assumes that rows for 'xvw_candy' and 'xvw_fruit' always exist in `sys_table`. Else, there is an additional path to `NOT FOUND`.

Don't confuse [SQL `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) with [PL/pgSQL `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). Same keyword, different language, subtly distinct syntax. Among other things, SQL `CASE` does not require an `ELSE` branch and defaults to `NULL`.

If the use case is as simple as your example suggests, you can even just look at the leading 5 characters and use the simpler "searched" `CASE` like you had in mind:

```
WHERE  sys_table_name = CASE left(TG_TABLE_NAME, 5)
                           WHEN 'candy' THEN 'xvw_candy'
                           WHEN 'fruit' THEN 'xvw_fruit'
                        END;
```

Or even just:

```
WHERE  sys_table_name = 'xvw_' || left(TG_TABLE_NAME, 5)
```

See:

- [Issue with composite type in an UPSERT function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33319/issue-with-composite-type-in-an-upsert-function/33322#33322)

Aside: it's typically better to store an actual `timestamptz` instead of an epoch as `bigint`. See:

- [How to best store a timestamp in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107475/how-to-best-store-a-timestamp-in-postgresql/107481#107481)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using your insights to further streamline my code, much appreciated. As for the timestamp, it's a bigint, because the application this DB is talking to selects from tables using an epoch number; why would it be better to store the epoch as a timestamptz?

Comment: @svenema: `timestamptz` and `bigint` are both 8-byte integer quantities internally, with the same storage characteristics and basically the same performance characteristics. The `bigint` representation is  meaningless to the human eye and lacks helpful sanity checks on input. Typically you store the result of `now()` and friends, which is cheaper without cast to `bigint`. And for all other date/time operations you need to cast to `timestamp`(`tz`) anyway. Typically, there is no good reason to use the inappropriate data type `bigint`.

Answer (score 1):

You’re using the searched syntax:

```
case a when ‘value’ then ... else ... end
```

whereas you should be using the expression syntax:

```
case when a like ‘...’ then ... else ... end
```